# Is it possible to build an iMessage bot for group chats?

Tags: chatbot, openai-api, imessage

I'm looking to write a bot using the OpenAI API for iMessage that works for group chats and can differentiate between users writing to be able to respond to each. I've looked far and wide for documentation on this and can't seem to find any. Some articles suggest this may be possible but nothing is definitive. Does anyone have firsthand experience with this or can point me to documentation? Thanks in advance!

I haven't yet started building.

Comment: `Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more. This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers.` Please limit your question to  a specific tangible focus, that has a realistic answer available to be given without needing to be documentation / links to it